# Get rid of parallel branches

Tags: git

Unfortunately I - as a Git rookie - did some unclean stuff and ended up with a Git log like this:

```
*   13c3cc7 (HEAD -> master, origin/master) everything merged
|\
| * 9457922 some other stuff here
* | 10b2e6f some stuff here
|/
* 5453269 solid last version
* ca9f9bf initial commit
```

As you can see, the commits 10b2 and 9457 are parallel, but do not build upon each other.

Now, ideally I would want a linear history going from 5453 over may one or two interim commits, up to 13c3.

Played around a bit with rebase, but to no avail. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

an interactive rebase should do the trick. Try

```
git rebase -i ca9f9bf
```

then adjust the commits as you like. For instance you can squash multiple together:

```
pick 5453269
pick 10b2e6f
fixup 9457922
pick 13c3cc7
```

Or simply leave them as they are, and they should end up being linearized.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have some outside constraints that force you to provide a linear history, don't even try to "fix" this: The history is exactly as it happened, and `git` was *designed* to deal with such histories really well.

Any attempt to "fix" it will result in a different history, which will essentially be a lie, with possible nasty consequences down the road. You would actually be making your history more difficult to deal with on the average.

I, for one, produce such forking history all the time, even when I'm the only person working on a project. My advise is to just relax and leave it as it is.